# Python SocketIO Client emit bytes

Tags: python, websocket, socket.io

I want to emit a `wav` file using the `socketIO-client-2` library. However, I get this error:

`'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xac in position 97: ordinal not in range(128)`

This is the relevant part for my code:

```
socketIO = SocketIO(IP, PORT, LoggingNamespace)
data = open('filename.wav', 'rb').read()
socketIO.emit('message', data[0:640])
```

I'm using `flask-socketIO` on the server like so:

```
socketio = SocketIO(app, binary=True)

@socketio.on('message')
def client(data):
    print data
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with your encoding not set to UTF-8

try this:

```
socketIO = SocketIO(IP, PORT, LoggingNamespace)
data = open('filename.wav', 'rb').read()
socketIO.emit('message', unicode(data[0:640],'utf-8'))
```

Comment: doesn't work. Using `binascii.hexlify(data[0:640])` to convert the data to ascii format works as a temporary fix